# Understanding Nested If.. Else statements

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my PHP login script keeps returning "invalid email/password combination", yet i know I am entering the correct email and password. Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
<?php

$email= $_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {

    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "si") or die('error connecting with the database');
    $query= "SELECT user_id, email, password FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND            
    password='$password'";
    $result= mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die('error with query');

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id']);
        echo "you are now logged in";
    } else {
        echo "invalid username/password combination";
    }

} else {
    echo" you must fill out both username and password";
}

?>
```

Comment: without good indentation, it is very difficult to understand your code...

Comment: @dqhendricks Just edited it! :-)

Comment: @dqhendricks it's fine in the source, just SO treats tabs as 4 spaces instead of the standard 8

Comment: 1) try `echo "|$email|"; echo"|$password|";` before performing the query. 2) are you SURE the db query works fine?

Comment: @tobyodavies It WAS pretty a mess before editing. What you see now, is... quite beautified... ;-)

Comment: also, your code is severely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I started editing before you, you just finished first. It read fine in chrome.

Comment: paste the result of var_dump($query) and var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result))

Answer (score 2):

I would switch it to say,

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

but other than that, the code looks like it should work. Are you sure that the $_POST variables contain what you think they should contain? Are you sure that this user/pass combination exist in your database?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. I'd check the following:

Make sure the query is working. I'd echo out the query and run it on your database in your DB program and see what the results are.

Make sure you don't have more than 1 user with that email/password combination - it'll bugger up your count check.

Check the details your posting and make sure they are correct to what you have in the database (No stray white spaces etc).

Finally, you'd be better off properly indenting and laying out your code, see how much easier it is to read here: http://codepad.org/DmtMuTpC

Answer (score 1):

you care getting that when `mysqli_num_rows ( $result )` is not equal to `1` ...  What i think you should do is verify if the `username` and `password` exist directly in the database ..... that is the only logical reason in your script why you should be getting `invalid username/password combination`

If you still have additional issue let me know

Comment: That's (mostly) true, but why does get an "invalid username" message? That would happen only if he has more than 1 user with the same password and e-mail...

Comment: it not advice-able to have more than 1 username and password but you can try `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` just to verify if that is where the error is coming form

Answer (score 0):

The error was appearing because there was duplicate data in the database.